# Can't override MUI TextField component's color

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

The below code:

```
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';
import { FormControl, TextField, InputLabel } from '@mui/material';
import styled from '@emotion/styled';

const ModalFormControl = styled(FormControl)`
  width: 100%;
`;

const ModalTextField = styled(TextField)`
  color: red;
`
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ModalFormControl>
        <Typography>Name</Typography>
        <ModalTextField />
        <Typography>Columns</Typography>
        <ModalTextField />
      </ModalFormControl>
    </div>
  );
}
```

For some reason, it doesn't override the color of the `TextField`. I am not messing with theme stuff at all so not sure where the default black color is coming from.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `styled()` utility the way to change the default input color of the TextField seems to be:

```
const ModalTextField = styled(TextField)({
  input: {
    color: 'white'
  }
});
```